# How to get the row index of last non-empty cell for a specific column name(passed as an argument) from an excel sheet using java?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

Abstract of the module which gets book name, sheet name and column name as arguments and expecting the module to return the desired row index.

```
public int getExcelData(String WBookName, String sheetName, String columnName) {

    int colNum = -1;
    int rowIndex = -1;
    InputStream inputStream =  getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/"+WBookName+".xls");
    try {
        excelWBook = new XSSFWorkbook(inputStream);
        Log.info(WBookName+"Excel File loaded Successfully");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.fatal("Unable to load"+WBookName+" Excel File");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    excelWSheet = excelWBook.getSheet(sheetName);
    row = excelWSheet.getRow(0);

    for(int i=0; i<row.getLastCellNum();i++) {
        if(row.getCell(i).getStringCellValue().trim().equals(columnName)){
            colNum = i;
        }
    }
    {
        //code for getting last non-empty row for a columnName (Possible using Iterator?)
    }
    return rowIndex;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Apache POI has the method [`Sheet#getLastRowNum()`](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Sheet.html#getLastRowNum()), I would use a for-loop going backwards from `excelWSheet.getLastRowNum()` to `0` and ask each row for a presence of a value.

The code would be *something like* (you should try it yourself, I am now just "programming in the browser") this:

```
for (int rowNum = excelWSheet.getLastRowNum(); rowNum >= 0; rowNum--) {
    final Row row = excelWSheet.getRow(rowNum);
    if (row != null && row.getCell(colNum) != null) {
        rowIndex = rowNum;
        break;
    }
}
```